# Xcode Parse Json Data

Tags: iphone, ios6

My code below was working, before, but suddenly it stopped working. Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Output of `NSLog()`:

```
2013-05-14 16:06:35.475 Run.PH[1502:19a03] background = (null)
2013-05-14 16:06:35.476 Run.PH[1502:19a03] logo = (null)
2013-05-14 16:06:35.476 Run.PH[1502:19a03] json = (null)
2013-05-14 16:06:35.476 Run.PH[1502:19a03] welcome = (null)
```

Codes:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://run.ph/json/test_json_dyna.jsp"];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    if(data != nil)
    {

        NSError *error;

        _json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

        _welcomeMessage.text = [[_json objectForKey:@"welcome"] objectForKey:@"message"];

        NSString *background = [[_json objectForKey:@"welcome"] objectForKey:@"background"];

        NSString *logo = [[_json objectForKey:@"welcome"] objectForKey:@"logo"];


        NSLog(@"background = %@", background);
        NSLog(@"logo = %@", logo);
        NSLog(@"json = %@", _json);
        NSLog(@"welcome = %@", _welcomeMessage.text);


        NSURL *urlBackground = [NSURL URLWithString:background];
        NSData *dataBackground = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlBackground];

        [_background setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:dataBackground]];

        NSURL *urlLogo = [NSURL URLWithString:logo];
        NSData *dataLogo = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlLogo];

        [_logo setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:dataLogo]];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Error!");
    }


    [self.view reloadInputViews];
}
```

Comment: I am doing in separate layer the NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]; with callbacks, for me it works

Comment: what do you mean by *doing it on a separate layer*?

Answer (score 0):

Just NSLog your URL response you will get wats wrong with your json.
Try this

```
NSString *respo = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];
NSLog(@"Response - %@",respo);
```

It has return "\r" and newline character "\n" with your response.

Check this

[image]

**EDIT**
Now your URL is working fine, problem was with your web service end.

Comment: i modified the json source but the result is the same. I was able to remove all preceeding space, new line and return, but i still cant load the data.

Comment: call  your web team to remove this new line and character

Comment: i tried using json viewer, everything looks fine on the it. Please see : http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/#http://www.run.ph/json/test_json_dyna.jsp

Comment: Hey check now,, your problem is solved now... problem was from your web service end